# Spring Security 3.2 XML configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know that this problem here very popular. But anyone didn't help me.

The problem is that I can't configure my `spring-security.xml` config file. I'm also have **404 error** on `/` page.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-data.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- utf8 Encoder -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/?error=true"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Please, help me with my problem. Thanks!

**===UPDATE===**

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/res/**" location="file:/home/piotr/Work/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/work-dir/res/" />

    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="fileUploadService" class="com.petrez.service.FileUploadServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="savePath" value="/home/piotr/Work/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/work-dir" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <annotation-config />

    <component-scan base-package="com.petrez" />

</beans:beans>
```

**spring-data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Library" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="G190419g" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.petrez" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.petrez.model.User</value>
                <value>com.petrez.model.Role</value>
                <value>com.petrez.model.Book</value>
                <value>com.petrez.model.BookGenre</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.petrez.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: 404 on "/" - do you have a controller(method) mapped to "/"?

Comment: @Evgeni of course. I just returned old spring xml configuration, that was before edit her.

Comment: Any exceptions in the log? If you remove the security does 404 apear again? Best way to deal with Spring Security problems is to enable the logging(log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=All for log4j) and trace how the requests are handled.

Answer (score 0):

@Petr, I know that this thread is a long back one, but my guess that you might have missed any of the following spring libraries,

- spring-security-core
- spring-security-web
- spring-security-context

*From Spring Security docs at **https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html**, I found the following quote*

> To start using the security namespace in your application context, you first need to make sure that the **spring-security-config.jar** is on your classpath. Then all you need to do is add the schema declaration to your application context file: