# Context initialization failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using JAVA 8, Spring security, hibernate and postGreSQL. I'm having this errors when starting Tomcat, the login page open but it's not entering it says invalid user, and all the info are right. I think it's something about versions but where do I need to change? is there anyone else wrong beyond this?

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Rastrbov</groupId>
    <artifactId>sisRastrbov</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <build>
        <finalName>sisRastrbov</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- núcleo do hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- implementação do Hibernate BeanValidator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- implementação do entityManager da Jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- weld - implementação do CDI -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mojarra (implementação do JSF 2) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Biblioteca de componentes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API de servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Lang (utilidades) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>    
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param> 
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
       <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
       <resource-env-ref-type>
          javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
       </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Main.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my stack trace:

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.__refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

out 07, 2016 10:59:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.__refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

GRAVE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.__stop(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is stated right here:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or
>   spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring
>   Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2
>   schema.

That means you need to update `applicationContext.xml` to use the 3.2 schema for spring security. Look for a 3.2 sample and copy from there.

There is a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499249/spring-security-3-2-xml-configuration) you can copy and paste from to get the correct declarations.

Comment: Mike, the error persists, don't I have to change only in applicationContext file? I updated the project, cleaned, and still persists...

Comment: I solved it with your answer! But now I get new errors. I will ask another question!